# Working with a bunch of single column txt files and seeing overlap via Pandas/python

Tags: python, dataframe, overlap, txt

I have a bunch of individual single-column text files(55 to be exact). The file names are super generic (text file (1).txt, text file (2).txt, etc). Each file is a plain text file that contains a name of the gene set as its first line, description as line 2, and then the actual list of genes(each is on a new line with no other characters):

I have all of these files in a folder. My goal is to somehow create a data frame that contains a nonredundant list of all the proteins that are found in the files in this folder and then have a second column that lists which pathways (aka line 1 of the file/files the protein can be found in) each protein is in. I am super new to coding and have been trying a bunch of things that just don't work! If anyone could help it would be much appreciated :)

Example of one of the text files.

```html
DACH1_TARGET_GENES
> Genes containing one or more binding sites for UniProt:Q9UI36 (DACH1) in their promoter regions (TSS -1000,+100 bp) as identified by GTRD version 20.06 ChIP-seq harmonization.
AAGAB
AAR2
ABCA7
ABCB10
ABHD17C
ABHD2
ABR
```

Expected output would be something like this (this is mimicking a two column dataframe)

```html
Protein   Datasets
AAGAB     ['Cancer_TargetGenes','Immune_System_Genes']
AFAWH     ['Cancer_TargetGenes','Cardiac_System_Genes']
ADSJA     ['Cancer_TargetGenes','Skin_System_Genes']
SADIJ     ['GI_TargetGenes']
```

Comment: Can you show a small sample of one or two of the files, AND a sample expected output dataframe? Thank you! :)

Comment: @richardec done! Lmk if my edit makes sense